# Uniform Continuity of a function that has a limit of 2

Tags: general-topology

Question: $f(x)$ is a function continuous on R and $f(x) -> 2 $ as $x-> \infty$. Is $f(x)$ uniformly continuous?

Attempt: I think the answer is yes. My idea for a proof is that you can use the definition of limit and choose an $x$ and $x^{'}$ s.t. $\left|f(x)-2)\right|<\epsilon/2$ and $\left|f(x^{'})-2\right|<\epsilon/2$, and then use the triangle inequality to get $\left|f(x)-f(x^{'})\right|<\epsilon$, and then taking $\delta$=$x-x^{'}$. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: If it uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ you're looking for, then $|f(x)-f(y)|$ should be small for ANY $x$, $y$ close enough.

Comment: Do you want to mean "as $x\to+\infty$" or "as $x\to\pm\infty$" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-x}+2$. Then $f$ meets your desired conditions, so let us check whether it is uniformly continuous. Let $\epsilon=1>0$. Then we must find a $\delta$ such that, for *any* $x$ and $y$ with $|x-y|\leq\delta$ then $|e^{-x}+2-(e^{-y}+2)|\leq1$. Let $y=x-\delta$. Then we need 
$$
|e^{-x}+2-(e^{-y}+2)|=|e^{-x}-e^{-x+\delta}|\leq1
$$
or 
$$
|e^{-x}(1-e^\delta)|\leq1
$$
again for *any* $x$. What happens when $x$ is negative and $|x|$ is large?

Comment: Ahh, I see. If $x$ is negative and its absolute value is very large, that inequality will be greater than 1. I understand the counterexample. Was there anything with my attempted solution wrong that led me to a wrong conclusion?

Comment: Essentially your solution only holds for when $x$ is very large in the positive direction (think of when $f$ is close enough to its limit to be $\epsilon$ away). Your method can be used to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[R,\infty)$ for a large $R$.